# How to pass generic type with extension restraint to a method in C#

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

I want to pass to the method `CreateCell()` the Type of a subclass that extends from Cell (in the example ReproducerCell). I am guessing that I should pass the Type itself extracted using `typeof(ReproducerCell)`, but I haven't been able to find the appropriate way to use that Type later on in `CreateCell()` while keeping the constraint.

What I first came up with is the first code block below, in which I create a new instance of the ReproducerCell, but I don't think it's the right way to do it, since I'm making an instantiation I don't need, because the type of the instance is all I need to know in `CreateCell()`.

```
public void CreateWorld() {
    //...
    for (int i = 0; i < INITIAL_POPULATION; i++) {
        cellsList.Add(CreateCell(new ReproducerCell()));
    }
}

private Cell CreateCell<T>(T cellSubclass) where T : Cell {
    //...
    Cell newCell = cellGO.GetComponent<T>();
    return newCell;
}
```

But then making some trial-error writing I came up with this:

```
public void CreateWorld() {
    //...
    for (int i = 0; i < INITIAL_POPULATION; i++) {
        cellsList.Add(CreateCell<ReproducerCell>());
    }
}

private Cell CreateCell<T>() where T : Cell {
    //...
    Cell newCell = cellGO.GetComponent<T>();
    return newCell;
}
```

which seems to be just right, but I wanted to check if specifying the type this way is the appropriate way to do it.

I am sure this has been asked before, but haven't been able to find the answer I was looking for.

Comment: If you don't need a `T` instance in `CreateCell`, then there's no need to declare a `T cellSubclass` parameter. Your first example is still implicitly calling `CreateCell<ReproducerCell>(new ReproducerCell())` anyway, just that `T` is being inferred from the argument.

Comment: You haven't included `cellGO.GetComponent`. Depending on your logic, adding a `new()` constraint so you can directly do `new T()` might also be appropriate/simpler.

Comment: Your 2nd solution is the correct way.